# Fade in data in viewDidAppear swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, fadein

So I currently have a collectionView and I am trying to implement an animation so that when the collectionView appears, the cells fade in all at once, once the data loads. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Set collection view's alpha to `0` & load your data in `viewDidLoad`. Then animate `collectionView.alpha = 1` in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`, add the following:

```
collectionView.alpha = 0
```

Then then in `viewDidAppear` add the following:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    collectionView.alpha = 1
}
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks for attributing :)